# Подготовка текста

Tags: редактор-текста

Для подготовки текстов для Андроид приложения требуется его форматировать (жирный, курсив, цвет, абзац). Как это делать с минимальными затратами? Может есть редакторы, где это делается как в ворде, или теги HTML надо забивать вручную?

Comment: Есть `markdown`

Comment: «как в ворде» называется WYSIWYG, если что